# Mounting database issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-migration

I have an issue with the site collections after updating my UAT environment with production data. I am trying to update my SharePoint 2016 UAT environment with the fresh data coming from production.

1. Backup the production database
2. Restored the backup file to different sql server
3. Create a new webapplication on UAT environment
4. Remove the db associated to newly created webapplication
5. Run the Mount-SPContentDatabase

The issue is after running the Mount-SPContent, it seems that it has completed without no issue. However when I check the site collections in UAT it still pointing to production environment and the URL hasn't changed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you Create a web application in the SharePoint Server 2016 environment. For the web application, do the following:

Use the same URL (including name, port, and host header) and configure alternate-access mapping settings.

If you use a different URL, Office applications might not be redirected correctly to the new URLs and all bookmarks to the old URLs will not work.

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-content-databases-2019

Comment: Thanks Lisa, I have followed the Microsoft recommendation and still after mounting the content database to dev environment the URL still pointing to prod instead of DEV. I did also import and install the certificate and still no hope. The root site collection has been migrated successfully however the other site collection with host header and https configuration still pointing to the prod